# Adding a place for JWT Bearer Token to Swagger Documentation in Restx

Tags: flask, jwt, flask-restx

I'm using the below structure

```
    authorizations = {
    'apikey': {
        'type': 'apiKey',
        'in': 'header',
        'name': 'X-API-KEY'
    }
}

api = Api(app, authorizations=authorizations)
```

But in the swagger ui, i'm giving my token directly and getting response

> Error: UNAUTHORIZED

Answer (score 1):

You need to add security parameter in your api initializations.

`api = Api(app, authorizations=authorizations, security='apikey'`)

Don't forget to refresh swagger page.